# How can I restart a TcpListener without a blocking port?

Tags: c#, port, tcplistener

I have a Receiver that uses TcpListener to receive messages. This includes the option to set an auto-restart on the Receiver, in case something causes it to lock up. The problem that I am having is that during the restart, the port is not being released after closing the listener. I know that Windows can keep the port open for 3 to 4 minutes, so I continue checking for five minutes before giving up. Sometimes, though, the port is never released, and the Receiver stops.

Does anyone know how I can shut down a TcpListener, and then immediately open a new one using the same port?

I've included a few snippets of code below:

Create the listener

```
server = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, Port);
server.Server.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, 1);
server.Start();
...
server.BeginAcceptTcpClient(new AsyncCallback(AcceptMessage), server);
```

Stop the listener

```
finally
{
    if (server != null)
        server.Stop();
    server = null;
    ...
```

Restart code

```
Stop();    
//  Check to make sure the port is released
bool isPortInUse = true;
int count = 0;

//  End when the port is no longer in use, or after 5 minutes
while (isPortInUse && count++ < 300)
{
    bool isAvailable = true;
    IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
    TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

    foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
    {
        if (tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port == Port)
        {
            isAvailable = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isAvailable)
        isPortInUse = false;
    else
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);    //  Wait one second
}

if (!isPortInUse)
Start();
```

Comment: There is no way a listener can legitimately "lock up", crash or fail after it has successfully started. There's a bug in your code. How do you determine that it "locks up"?

Comment: A TcpListener  is a server application and should be a slave to the client(s) application.  Closing a connection from a server is never a good idea.  A connection is always open/close from the client application.  A connection should always close in seconds, not minutes.  There is probably something else occurring that is not closing the connection.

Comment: Further, you should be able to use the same port immediately thanks to address reuse. Why does that not work?

Comment: @usr - There is most certainly a bug somewhere in the code, and I am ultimately trying to find and resolve that. The auto-restart was made as a patch, since I am unable to reproduce the bug. The Receiver is made to be left on, and some clients, after a month or more of constant use, will sometimes run into an issue where messages are no longer being received. Something in processing is causing an error that I have not been able to catch in logging yet. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Sounds like connection processing is broken, not *accepting* connections. This patch would not help.